# Unable to install geopandas using conda install

Tags: arcgis-pro, installation, geopandas, anaconda

I'm trying to install GeoPandas using the Command Prompt terminal. I have Python 3 and ArcGIS installed. I keep getting these messages that say there is a conflict with various packages. For example:

Package jupyterlab_launcher conflicts for:
jupyterlab -> jupyterlab_launcher[version='<0.2|>=0.10.0,<0.11.0|>=0.11.2,<0.12.0|>=0.13.1,<0.14.0|>=0.6.0,<0.7.0|>=0.5.4,<0.6.0|>=0.5.4|>=0.4.0|>=0.3.0|>=0.2.3|>=0.11.0,<0.12.0']
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf -> jupyterlab -> jupyterlab_launcher[version='<0.2|>=0.10.0,<0.11.0|>=0.11.2,<0.12.0|>=0.13.1,<0.14.0|>=0.6.0,<0.7.0|>=0.5.4,<0.6.0|>=0.5.4|>=0.4.0|>=0.3.0|>=0.2.3|>=0.11.0,<0.12.0']

I used both `conda install -c conda-forge geopandas` and `conda install --channel conda-forge geopandas`.

Comment: Is it ArcGIS Desktop or ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: Have you tried `conda install geopandas`?

Comment: The ArcGIS Pro envs have a few pinned packages that can cause conflicts when trying to install from conda-forge. Try just the default as suggested by @Aaron, or create a separate non-ArcGIS env

Comment: Have you cloned or created a new environment? Per [Python Package Manager](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/what-is-conda.htm), since Pro 2.2 you **cannot** install into the default environment.

Comment: I was getting this yesterday. Had to install the full Anaconda programme to fix it.